# Setting height for tabBarItemStyle cuts off label react-navigation/material-top-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm trying to customize top bar
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIwLR.png)
When I tried to set height, the label didn't move up like I expected. Instead it was [cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWwV.png)

What did I do wrong? Need help

Here's my code

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const TabNav = (navigation: any, route: any) => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Tab1"
    screenOptions={{
      swipeEnabled: false,
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14,
        textTransform: 'none',
        position: 'relative',
      },
      tabBarIndicatorStyle: {backgroundColor: '#F69300'},
      tabBarItemStyle: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 30,
        paddingBottom: 10,
        position: 'relative',
      },
      tabBarPressColor: '#FFF',
      tabBarPressOpacity: 0,
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab1"
      component={FirstTab}
      initialParams={route.params}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Text cut gggg',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <MaterialIcons color={color} size={size} name="online-prediction" />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab2"
      component={SecondTab}
      initialParams={route.params}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Text cut gggg',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <MaterialIcons color={color} size={size} name="online-prediction" />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Tab3"
      component={ThirdTab}
      initialParams={route.params}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Text cut gggg',
        tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
          <MaterialIcons color={color} size={size} name="online-prediction" />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default Contact;
```

I thought it was `position: 'absolute'` so I set it to `relative` but I supposed it was not the problem
Also I want icon and label to inline but it also didn't work with `justifyContent: 'center'` and `alignItems: 'center'`